# Reference another table in ASP.NET without a foreign key or joining tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have read-only access to a database. This database has multiple tables with status codes and one other reference table the gives a name for each code. These tables are not linked by a foreign key and I can't alter the database in any way. I'd like to display the status names in my web-app view instead of the numeric status code, is there a way to do this? Using EF Core 6

I tried to join the two tables but it didn't match the model in the View. I don't know how to remedy this situation without creating a new table (which I can't do)

Comment: Why not just lookup the status code.  Remember that you can create your own class in the controller and bind that or a list of those classes to your view.

Comment: How would I do this? Are you saying I could join the two tables, load them into a new class that is created in the controller (within the Index?), and use that class as my model in the view without creating a new table in the daabase?

Comment: you don't need a join.  You have the status code so just look up the status in another request.  Maybe I'm not understanding something here?